# array.map iterates over an array to return an object array

Tags: javascript

Suppose I would like to turn an array of

```
let originalArray = [a,b,c]
```

into an array of such format:

```
[{0:a},{1:b},{2:c}]
```

I was using map function to iterate over the originalArray as such

```
originalArray.map((val, i) => {i:val})
```

However it returns all undefined values. My question is how can I use map function to achieve my intended result?

Comment: It is interpreting the `{}` as a block not an object. Wrap the curly braces in parens. (This is only one of the things stopping this working)

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `[]` notation for the property name to evaluate the expression and use the value under it. Also wrap your returned object with `()` brackets, without this the compiler understands the starting `{` of the object as the arrow functions body start and gives wrong result.

```js
let originalArray = ['a','b','c'];
let mappedArray = originalArray.map( (item, index) => ({[index]: item}));

console.log(mappedArray);
```

Your code snippet is like this one, which, if you don't explicitly return anything, it by default returns undefined.

```js
let originalArray = ['a','b','c'];
let mappedArray = originalArray.map( (item, index) => {
    index: item;
    return undefined;
});

console.log(mappedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your arrow function is syntactically incorrect because, in that context, `{` and `}` are interpreted as block delimiters:

```
(val, i) => {i:val} // Here '{' and '}' are a block delimiters.
```

You need to, at least, enclose it between parentheses to force it to be interpreted as object expression:

```
(val, i) => ({[i]:val}) // This works.
// Also notice the '[' and ']' surrounding "i" meaning that the
// value of i should be used as key instead of actual "i".
```

Think about this:

```
(val, i) => {i, val}
```

...What it is supposed to return? `{i:<i_value>, val:<val_value>}` or undefined (because `i, val` evaluates to *val* value, but while enclosed in block delimiters, you need to explicitly user *'return'* statement:

```
$ node
> let f = (x)=>{x+1}
undefined
> f(3)
undefined
> let f = (x)=>{return x+1}
undefined
> f(3)
4
```

Alternatively you could do something like this, but, in this case the use of arrow function would become pointless IMHO:

```
(val, i) => {return {i:val}}
```